# How to correctly remove a version name from a file request?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using a cache-busting mechanism which includes a version name in every resource on my page.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/viewnote.<?php echo VERSION; ?>.css" />
```

Output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/viewnote.100.css" />
```

The name of the real file is viewnote.css, therefore, I need to remove the version number using htaccess.

I've used this [example](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/355):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
```

but it doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just make the version a parameter like `viewnote.css?110`?

Comment: I could but [link](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/) recommends to use the approach I've chosen.

Comment: Are the "\" in your rewrite rule correct? I see it being: `RewriteRule ^(.+).(d+).(js|css)$ $1.$3 [L]`

Comment: @ride_85027 `\.` is because he wants a literal `.` not the wildcard for any character. As for the regex syntax, nevermind what I said on `.+` vs `.+?`; what you have works for me in TextPad. May be something different from the syntax for .htaccess files

Comment: @developerwjk ah yes, thanks for that info!

Comment: I have tried changing `.+` to `.+?` but it still doesn't work. I've seen a few different versions with "/" or without it on the site I linked in my previous comment as well as in the comments below that post. None of them worked, so I have decided to try the expression linked in my question but that doesn't work as welll.

Comment: RewriteEngine is on, so it's propably a problem of the configuration of my server. I will try to experiment with it a bit.

Comment: Is there a way to log these rewrites?

Comment: I've found the problem. Some rule defined later in my htaccess interferes with this one. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have RewriteEngine On

Also, I've added the PT flag (Pass-through) so it goes to the file but retains the Version URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [PT,L]
```